# Vb.Net Startup Determination

Tags: vb.net

Hello everyone i'll keep it short and simple.
I want the app to determine if the current app (which is called "Managment") is on startup. If it is on the startup then do nothing.. if it isnt there put it on startup.
What is wrong with this? And is there any way without admin rights?

```
Dim app As String = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).GetValue("Management")
    If app = Nothing Then
        My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath)
    End If
```

Comment: `Application.ProductName` may not be `"Management"`

Comment: it is. is something wrong on the code?

Comment: Additionally, you ask `What is wrong with this?` when it would be far more helpful if you told us what is wrong so we could help fix it.

Comment: if you cant answer then dont bother there are plenty of useres to help me out

Comment: Ok.  See how far you get with that attitude.

Comment: You need to look at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and not `LocalMachine`

Comment: dont even care if you downvote. i seek an answer

Comment: @436f6465786572 Can you explain please?thankss :D

Comment: All kinds of good reasons NOT to do this at all.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what u mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you are looking in the wrong place.

```
Using subKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
  If subKey.GetValue("Management") <> Nothing Then
    'It's there on start-up 
  Else
    'Just add the key....
  End If
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks ill test it out